# Generate percent change between annual observations in Stata?

Tags: stata

How do I use the `gen` or `egen` commands to generate the percent change between observations for different years in Stata? For example, I have observations for 1990 through 2010, each with a different value for expenditures, and I'm trying to generate a new observation with the percent change from 1990-1991, 1991-1992, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// Here's an example with another measure of growth:

```
clear
set obs 100
gen year = _n + 1959
gen expenditure = _n^(1/3) + runiform()
line expenditure year, yti("Synthetic data example")
```

// [From Statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-10/msg00648.html):

```
bys year: g expendituregrowth=100*(expenditure[_n]-expenditure[_n-1])/expenditure[_n-1]
```

// Also:

```
gen expenditure_gr = (expenditure/expenditure[_n-1] - 1)*100 // growth rate for expenditure
gen expenditure_bl = 100*expenditure/expenditure[1] // baseline growth rate for expenditure; base 100 = 1960

line expenditure_gr year, yti("Growth rate")
line expenditure_bl year, yti("Growth rate (base 100 = 1960)")
```

// The computation of `expenditure_gr` is what I think you are looking for.

// If your data are well-formed, use Stata with time series and get the growth rate easily:

```
tsset year, delta(1)
cap drop expenditure_gr
gen expenditure_gr = D.expenditure / 100*L.expenditure
```

Comment: The last line will only create the difference; to create the growth rate equivalent to your previous definition of `exp_gr`, it should be `gen exp_gr = D.exp/L.exp*100`. Also, `exp` is an absolutely terrible name for a variable: if you forget multiplication sign in `exp*(stuff1+stuff2)`, you will spend an hour looking for this bug (once somebody notes that your numbers are extraordinarily large).

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Sorry about taking so long to accept your answer, but it is very helpful.

Comment: Hi, I cam across this post and was wondering whether the correct way of obtaining projection for the data set that is `xtset` would be `bys panel date: gen variable_gr = D.variable/L.variable*100`? Running the command without the `bys` prefix returned the *not sorted* error.

Comment: Sounds good. You can `sort` the data prior to the computation, as a separate command.