# Stata: sales growth rate of multiple groups

Tags: stata

Cross-posting:
german: http://www.stata-forum.de/post1716.html#p1716
english: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/47299-sales-growth-rate-with-multiple-groups-conditions

I want to calculate the annual sales growth rate of different firm-groups in Stata. The firms are grouped by variables `country` and `industry`.

I summed sales for each group (called it `sales_total`: sales of all firms in a group with equal `country`, `industry` and `year`):

```
bysort country year industry: egen sales_total = sum(sales)
```

I have a much bigger sample, but I tried to calculate the growth-rate with a smaller sample.

I tried multiple combinations such as:

```
egen group = group(year country industry)
xtset group year, yearly
bys group: g salesgrowth = log(D.sales_total)
```

or

```
bysort group: gen salesgrowth=(sales[_n]-sales[_n-1])/sales[_n-1]*
```

also with `tsset`.

and tried everything from this answer:
[Generate percent change between annual observations in Stata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254082/generate-percent-change-between-annual-observations-in-stata/10259827#10259827)

but I always get error messages such as

```
  repeated time values within panel
```

or

```
 repeated time values within sample
```

due to the repetition of the number in a variable such as `group`.

Can you help me to find the yearly growth rate from each group (firms from same `country` & `industry`)?

**update**

here again an example of my observations (which normally have 10,000 firms over 10 years). There are also missing values (for sales, industry, year, country)

firms -- country -- year -- industry -- sales

-a --------usa-------1----------1----------300

-a---------usa-------2----------1--------4000

-b---------ger-------1----------1--------200

-b---------ger-------2----------1--------400

-c---------usa------1----------1----------100

-c---------usa------2----------1----------300

-d---------usa------1----------1----------400

-d---------usa------2----------1----------200

-e---------usa------1----------1----------7000

-e---------usa------2----------1----------900

-f----------ger------1----------2----------100

-f---------ger------2----------2----------700

-h---------ger------1----------2----------700

-h---------ger------2----------2----------600

-.................etc.....................................

I tried the programing you mentioned, but I got a couple of variables that need to be used in the same row and not in the same column (which I would probably need). Is there a possibility to keep the data without reshaping, keeping them in a row, for example grouping the observations:

`egen group=group(industry year country)`

and then try

`xtset group year
bysort group: sales_growth = log(D.sales)`
or
`bysort group: gen sales_growth = (sales[_n]-sales[_n-1])/sales[_n-1]`

Thank you!

Comment: Cross-posting at http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/47299-sales-growth-rate-with-multiple-groups-conditions

Comment: Running threads in parallel on different websites without informing both sites is in my view poor behaviour: leads to duplicated effort.

Comment: sorry, I thought that both sites are not at all linked to each other! I thought that it would not matter as there are different users on both sites.

Comment: If there are completely different users on each site, which is not true, why should they want to duplicate effort?

Comment: I posted the question on one site. As no one replied, I thought that I would not get an answer and posted the question on another site.
It won't happen again. If I do, I'll post a link on all sites that are related!
Best regards and sorry again, Franz

Comment: Strictly not true. You posted here on July 19, did get a reply here, and then posted on Talkstats on July 20. All a matter of public record. Thanks for the reassurances, however.

Comment: Dear Nick, I could still use some help concerning the problem that I would like to keep the rest of the data without using the command `collapse` because I need to do the same operation for other industries? Is that possible? Of course if you still want to help me.(sorry again, I edited the post on Talkstats)

I tried
`bysort country industry year: egen sum_sales = sum(sales)
egen group_new = group(countrycode industry)
tsset group_new year
bysort group_new: gen sales_growth_ = (sum_sales[_n]-sum_sales[_n-1])/sum_sales[_n-1]`

But here again the error 451 comes up: repeated time values. Thanks

Comment: My advice remains what it was on July 19: use `collapse`.

Comment: This was cross-posted on http://www.stata-forum.de/stata-syntax-f18/wachstums-berechnung-abhangigkeit-mehrerer-variablen-t471.html The promise to post a link on all sites in the event of cross-posting was not kept.

Comment: edited it. I did not think that english-speaking persons would view german internet sites.

Comment: Incorrect again. Also, many German-speaking people view English language sites, as important. It's the same question: (a) if you yourself use two or more sites, why shouldn't others? (b) someone on stata-forum duplicated effort.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy here is trying to work at the wrong level of resolution. You should

```
collapse (sum) sales, by(country year industry)
```

and then work with that reduced dataset. Depending on what you want precisely, you will probably need to restructure that data with `reshape` so that different industries give different variables. Then

```
xtset country year
```

and growth rates will then be easier to calculate.

Comment: I couldn't post an image due to the reputation-points I need.

Comment: Nothing stops you posting sample data. They don't have to be complete, or even real, just enough to give a real flavour of your problem.

Comment: dear @Nick, the problem is (just like the other problem I posted) I would like to keep the data in the rows, as it is currently, due to a lot of other variables that I calculate.

See above after update for more information. Thank you